# Set workflow status description directly

Tags: bash, github, github-actions, github-api

I'm running a custom GitHub workflow and I want to add a custom status description like so:

[image: status check with description]

My issue is that I can't seem to be able to do it other than over the GitHub commit status API, which creates an entirely new status and doesn't link it to the job I was running, via:

```bash
curl -L \
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/statuses/${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} \
    -d '{"state":"'"${status}"'","target_url":"${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}","description":"'"${description}"'","context":"Release plan"}' \
    --fail
```

Which results in this because the status is not considered part of the same job run:

[image: double statuses]

Is there a way I can edit this description directly from my workflow job, which looks like this:

```yaml
    - run: |
        body=$(gh pr view ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} --json 'body' --jq '.body')
        notRequired=$(echo "$body" | { grep -i '\- \[x\] No release plan' || test $? = 1; } | wc -l)
        complete=$(echo "$body" | { grep -i '\- \[x\] release plan complete' || test $? = 1; } | wc -l)
        if [ "$notRequired" -ne "0" ]; then
          echo "No release plan required" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          exit 0
        elif [ "$complete" -ne "0" ]; then
          echo "Release plan complete" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          exit 0
        else
          echo "::error::Release plan incomplete"
          exit 1
        fi
        echo "::error::Unexpected error"
        exit 1
```